# OffsetDateTime persisted by JPA differs by 2 hours

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA entity class with an `OffsetDateTime` field like this:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity(clock: Clock) {
    // ...
    val created: OffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(clock)
}
```

In a repository test I check that the date is corretly mapped:

```
assertThat(entity.created).isEqualTo(defaultDateTime)
```

If I compare the underlying `Instant` (and not also the offset) with `OffsetDateTime#isEqual` it works:

```
assertThat(entity.created.isEqual(defaultDateTime)).isTrue()
```

`defaultDateTime` and the `clock` are created with this code:

```
val defaultDateTime: OffsetDateTime =
    OffsetDateTime.of(2019, 6, 15, 11, 48, 59, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC)

fun createTestClock(dateTime: OffsetDateTime = defaultDateTime) = 
    Clock.fixed(dateTime.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC"))
```

But if I run my test, the time differs by exactly 2 hours (what is the actual offset in my region, central europe). The PostgreSQL database returns `GMT` if I query the timezone with `show timezone;`.

The column data type is:

```
timestamp with time zone not null
```

Setting the respective Hibernate property doesn't help:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What is the column's data type?

Comment: It is `timestamp with time zone not null`.

Comment: You query with `show time zone` all the time or just when debugging? Two `OffsetDateTime`s are equal only if offsets are also equal.

Comment: The date differs all the time (and not only while debugging).

Comment: I haven't dug very deep into the Hibernate implementation, but I found the conversion of `java.sql.Timestamp` into `ZonedDateTime` (inside `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ZonedDateTimeJavaDescriptor`) is implemented as `timestamp.toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())`. I suspect this might explain why `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` gets ignored

Comment: So you're saying it looks "wrong" within psql, but does hibernate extract it correctly? Also on our test and production systems, it just works without setting `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone`, but when you look at it through psql it returns the results in the local time that psql is running.

Comment: Where is the persisted date wrong? When you query it on the actual db, or when you query it via JPA or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that UTC and GMT have a (UTC) time offset of 0. Central Europe uses CET (Central European Time), which currently has an (UTC) offset of +2. This would explain the answer being off by 2hrs.

I would recommend maybe setting the default timezone in java (in your main application)

```java
@PostConstruct
void started() {
  TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}
```

and/or change the DB Timezone like

```java
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC;
```

to

```java
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=CET;
```

I think the issue may be java using your default timezone on your machine. When it compares the Entity I believe it compares them as UTC strings, so they would match, but if you compare the offset, your local may be CET (+2) while the timestamp is UTC/GMT (+0)

This is one possibility, just my knowledge of Java and Postrges more than Spring.